# Bizarre looping in python?

Tags: python

I'm new to python, but I come from a basic java background. There are learning curves to face, and so I'm having troubles. With this loop particularly...

```
from random import randint;
class simpleAI:
inputMatter = 0;
inputEnergyString = 0;
inputEnergy = 0;
resultMatter = 0;
resultEnergy = 0;
inputMatterMemory = [];
inputEnergyMemory = [];
resultMatterMemory = [];
resultEnergyMemory = [];
searchIndex = 0;
found = 0;
lookin = 0;
lookingEnergy = 0;

def cycle(self):
    self.inputMatter = input("Matter: ");
    self.inputMatter = int(self.inputMatter, 10);
    self.inputMatterMemory.append(self.inputMatter);
    self.inputEnergyString = input("Energy: ");
    self.inputEnergy = int(self.inputEnergyString, 10);
    self.inputEnergyMemory.append(self.inputEnergy);
    #Check for an event that resulted in positive energy
    while(self.searchIndex < self.resultEnergyMemory.__len__()):
        print("we are foring!");
        if(self.inputEnergyMemory.__getitem__((self.inputMatterMemory.index(self.inputMatter))) == self.inputEnergy):
             print("we are iffy!");
             self.resultMatter = self.resultMatterMemory.__getitem__(self.inputMatterMemory.index(self.inputMatter));
             self.resultEnergy = self.resultEnergyMemory.__getitem__(self.inputEnergyMemory.index(self.inputEnergy));
             self.found = 1;
             break;

        else:
            self.searchIndex = self.searchIndex + 1;

    if(self.found == 0):
        self.resultMatter = randint(0, 256);
        self.resultMatterMemory.append(self.resultMatter);
        self.resultEnergy = randint(0, 256);
        self.resultEnergyMemory.append(self.resultEnergy);
        print("Creating new pair...");
        print("Result matter: ", self.resultMatter);
        print("Result Energy: ", self.resultEnergy);
    elif(self.found == 1):
        print("Found positive pair from memory");
        print("Result matter: ", self.resultMatter);
        print("Result memory: ", self.resultEnergy);

    self.inputMatter = 0;
    self.inputEnergyString = 0;
    self.inputEnergy = 0;
    self.resultMatter = 0;
    self.searchIndex = 0;
    self.found = 0;
```

It produces the right result the first iteration, but falls back to "creating" a new pair on other iterations, even when it's supposed to return a pair when entered in before. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Once you get this working make a post over on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as it's a good chance to learn some things about writing cleaner Python code.

Comment: For one thing, your indentation in the class definition is broken. I'll assume that's a transcription error.

Comment: _"... even when it's supposed to return a pair"_. What do you mean? I don't see a `return` statement in this code.

Comment: Can you add some information about what this is supposed to do? From what I'm seeing, it takes in values for matter and energy and looks to see if those input values have been seen before. If they have, the corresponding results are printed out. If not, random results are created and stored for those inputs, and then printed out. Is this correct?

Comment: shuttle, I'll post it on coderview, thank you!

Comment: Tom, it was indeed a transcription error. I had to open it in notepad as I am not on my home computer right now. I just needed to post this asap.

Comment: Kevin, it takes values for matter and energy as integers. It then checks to see if they've been encountered before. If they have, they're printed. If not, it creates random integers that correspond to matter and energy, appends those to a list for future reference, and prints those. I didn't mean return in the literal sense, my apologies.

Comment: Roger, this is exactly what it is supposed to do. Strange, I know, but there's a philosophy behind it that I'd be happy to explain. If you, or anyone else, are interested, email me at OrangeCalx01@gmail.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a lot of extra work for yourself. Instead of trying to maintain multiple parallel arrays, you can simply make a separate class to hold all the data together and just have a single array of that class to loop through.

```
from random import randint;

class MatterEnergyData:
    def __init__(self, inputMatter, inputEnergy, resultMatter, resultEnergy):
        self.inputMatter = inputMatter
        self.inputEnergy = inputEnergy
        self.resultMatter = resultMatter
        self.resultEnergy = resultEnergy

    def __str__(self):
        return "Result matter: %s\r\nResult energy: %s" % \ 
            self.resultMatter, self.resultEnergy

class simpleAI:
    matterEnergyDataPoints = []

    def cycle(self):
        inputMatter = int(input("Matter: "))
        inputEnergy = int(input("Energy: "))
        resultObj = None
        for obj in self.matterEnergyDataPoints:
            if obj.inputEnergy == inputEnergy and obj.inputMatter == inputMatter:
                print("Found positive pair from memory")
                resultObj = obj
                break

        if resultObj == None:
            print("Creating new pair...")
            resultObj = MatterEnergyData(inputMatter, inputEnergy, randint(0, 256), randint(0, 256))
            self.matterEnergyDataPoints.append(resultObj)

        print resultObj
```